# How can I best put a drop down list or select tag inside a html table - And then update a row if changed to mysql? complicated

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have a database containing  a name and a status column. It contains data displayed in a table (obvious!). So, I want users to be able to select the status column's data and change it to any value listed in the drop down list. After the selection, they need to click a button that will update the selected row to the mySQL database.

How can I achieve this with PHP scripting and HTML?

Here is my code for displaying the data in a table on the website: (Pay no attention to phpReportGenerator.php- its only drawing the columns as per sql table)

```
 <?php


include_once('includes/phpReportGenerator.php'); 
$prg = new phpReportGenerator(); 
$prg->width = "100%"; 
$prg->cellpad = "10"; 
$prg->cellspace = "0.5"; 
$prg->border = "1"; 
$prg->header_color = "#307D7E"; 
$prg->header_textcolor="#FFFFFF"; 
$prg->body_alignment = "left"; 
$prg->body_color = "#C6DEFF"; 
$prg->body_textcolor = "#000000"; 
$prg->surrounded = '1'; 
//$prg->font_name = "Boishakhi"; 

mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
mysql_select_db("my_database"); 
$res = mysql_query("select * from table"); 
$prg->mysql_resource = $res;


//$prg->title = "Test Table"; 
$prg->generateReport(); 

?>
```

OR

Can somebody show me a easier/more effective way to do this?

Comment: I would recommend you look into jQuery/Ajax for this.

Comment: use onchange jquery function to trigger the ajax request and send the id and data to be updated with that request to a separate php file which will actually execute the mysql query for you... is this helpfull to you?

Comment: Thanks @SagarGuhe . Do you maybe have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code that you can use to update your mysql database by sending request to the server to access process_mysql.php :

```
<select onchange="update_mysql();">
    <option value="1">option 1 </option>
    <option value="2">option 2 </option>
</select>
```

Jquery function with ajax post request:

```
<script>
update_mysql(){
         var id = $('select option:selected').val();  
    $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"process_mysql.php",
                data:"id="+id,
                success:function(data){
                    alert('Successfully updated mysql database');
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: You welcome... ;) 
P.s. : edited the code the code was getting the value from selected option.